# How do i stop xinetd mysql service check to log every success?

Tags: mysql-cluster, xinetd

How do I stop xinetd mysql service check to log every success? It creates a log entry every second the check is successful, I cant use log_on_failure as the service just checks mysqld and turns status=1 in case it is not running.

Below is my `mysqlchck` script

```
service mysqlchk
{
        # this is a config for xinetd, place it in /etc/xinetd.d/
        disable = no
        flags           = REUSE IPv4
        socket_type     = stream
        port            = 9200
        wait            = no
        user            = nobody
        server          = /vvond/install/vvond-clustercheck
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        only_from       = 0.0.0.0/0
        #
        # Passing arguments to clustercheck
        # <user> <pass> <available_when_donor=0|1> <log_file> <available_when_readonly=0|1> <defaults_extra_file>"
        # Recommended: server_args   = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 0 /etc/my.cnf.local"
        # Compatibility: server_args = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 1 /etc/my.cnf.local"
        # 55-to-56 upgrade: server_args = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 0 /etc/my.cnf.extra"
        #
        # recommended to put the IPs that need
        # to connect exclusively (security purposes)
        per_source      = UNLIMITED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a blank entry for log_on_success and restart xinetd.

`{
...
log_on_success = 
...}`